# jQuery change from click to hover

Tags: jquery, menu, hover

I have a problem with jQuery. I created a menu with the function `.click` but now I need to trasform this menu in a hover menu when I click on the link COLLECTIONS.

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div#toggle a.button").click(function () {
    $("div#toggle div.box").toggle("slow");
});
hidden = true;
$("div#custom a.button").hover(function () {
  if(hidden == false) {
    $("div#custom div.box").fadeOut();
    hidden = true;
  } else {
    $("div#custom div.box").fadeIn(100);
    hidden = false;
  }
});
```

This is the CSS code:

```
#custom {
  z-index:0;
}

.box {
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  border:0px solid #999;
  background-color:rgb(128, 129, 132);
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  margin-top:6px;
  z-index:0;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color:#E6E4D7;
}
```

The page is at http://www.mediaxsrl.it/web/loloey/forme/formeit.html

Comment: there is a way to adapt the jquery code without change the css?

Comment: anyone that can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#custom").hover(function() { 
    $(this).find("box").slideDown(); 
} , function() {  
    $(this).find("box").hide(); 
});
```

Comment: I try it but when i mouse out the link Collection and go on the sub menu the sub menu disappear.

Comment: try to replace the first line with this:

$("#custom, .box").hover(function() {

Comment: I try but nothing changed.the menu above when I leave the hover continued to disappear.